# Why there were some json file generated automatically in changes(staging status) when I run git add using command lines?

Tags: git

[3 unexpected files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo7pc.png)

There are only two .txt files in this folder, but after I run git add ., and then checked its status, I found that there 3 unexpected files which are .lhignore and two .json files. I didn't do any setting for this folder to generate them. What is the most possible reason for that and how can I deal with it? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using this VS Code extension? https://github.com/xpodev/local-history

Comment: *Git* did not create them. Git knows nothing of json. (Well, there are some tools in the CI builds now, but they're not part of normal everyday Git.)

Comment: Thanks guys, I think it's because of the extension.